# Selenium does not find element on page (ruby, watir)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I can not locate the element on the page in any way, and I would not like to use xpath because the layout of the page can be changed later and complex to maintain.

I tried the following ways:

**Page Structure**

```
<select class="form-control errorClass1" id="idPage:idForm10:adhPaymentMethodId" name="adhPaymentMethodId">
<option value="0">Escolha um</option>
<option value="CreditCard">Cartão de Crédito</option>
<option value="Boleto">Boleto</option>
</select>
```

**Attempts**

```
@browser.select_list(:name, "adhPaymentMethodId").click
@browser.option(:text, "Boleto").click

@browser.select_list(:id, "idPage:idForm10:adhPaymentMethodId").click
@browser.option(:text, "Boleto").click

@browser.select_list(:id, "idPage:idForm10:adhPaymentMethodId").option.wait_until_present
sleep 1
@browser.option(:value, "Boleto").click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@browser.select_list(:name, "adhPaymentMethodId").select("Boleto")
```

If it's not working, let me know what error it is throwing

Comment: Perfect, Simple and functional.
Thank you